# Make fetch_assoc match fetch_all exactly

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

How do I match exactly the output of `fetch_all` with a loop using `fetch_assoc`?  I have built code around `fetch_all` but my Bluehost server with PHP 5.4 isn't sufficient to run it (I'm talking to them about it).  Here is what I've been using and it doesn't work:

```
public function getAllRecords($query) {
  $results = array();
  $r = $this->conn->query($query) or die($this->conn->error.__LINE__);
  while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
    $results[] = $row;
  }

  return $results;
}
```

**EDIT**

This function works but only returns one result:

```
public function getOneRecord($query) {
  $r = $this->conn->query($query.' LIMIT 1') or die($this->conn->error.__LINE__);
  return $result = $r->fetch_assoc();    
}
```

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: Doesn't return usable data.

Comment: are you conncet to db?where is your query?

Comment: My other function (in edit) works, only this one does not.  My exact query is `'select * from nodes'`, which works in the development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have `$results` containing the output exactly like that of of `fetch_all`, you can use this loop:

```
while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
    $results[] = array_values($row);
}
```

or just using `fetch_row` in the loop:

```
while ($row = $r->fetch_row()) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: In my answer below, you will see that `fetch_assoc` does not provide an equivalent to `fetch_all`, at least I think when using `mysqlnd`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know why my question was down-voted, it is legitimate.  `fetch_all` as I was using it before, returns an array of rows as arrays.  All my functions were based on parsing these arrays to their key values.

`fetch_assoc` returns an associative array, which is interpreted in Javascript as an object.  Of course, my array-based parsing functions don't like that and **that also means that `fetch_assoc` in a loop is NOT equivalent to `fetch_all`**.

What is equivalent is `fetch_row`.  The correct answer:

```
public function getAllRecords($query) {
  $results = array();
  $r = $this->conn->query($query) or die($this->conn->error.__LINE__);
  while ($row = $r->fetch_row()) {
    $results[] = $row;
  }

  return $results;
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what my answer says, - or `array_values` of `fetch_assoc`!

Comment: OH I missed that, my bad.